# How to change the SIM card within WWAN adapter without rebooting linux?

Tags: linux, networking, modem, sim, wwan

I am using a WWAN network adapter (Fibocom L850GL) that support SIM cards.

My OS is Debian 10, and so far I need to restart my computer in order to use it.

This is what happen:

```
sudo service ModemManager status
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-12 21:28:52 CET; 25min ago
 Main PID: 911 (ModemManager)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 12.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
           ├─ 911 /usr/sbin/ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
           └─1186 /usr/lib/libmbim/mbim-proxy

Dec 12 21:49:11 dka ModemManager[911]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (home -> unknown)
Dec 12 21:49:11 dka ModemManager[911]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disabling -> disabled)
Dec 12 21:52:20 dka ModemManager[911]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disabled -> enabling)
Dec 12 21:52:21 dka ModemManager[911]: <warn>  could not load SIM identifier: SimNotInserted (3 retries left)
Dec 12 21:52:22 dka ModemManager[911]: <warn>  could not load SIM identifier: SimNotInserted (2 retries left)
Dec 12 21:52:23 dka ModemManager[911]: <warn>  could not load SIM identifier: SimNotInserted (1 retries left)
Dec 12 21:52:24 dka ModemManager[911]: <warn>  could not load SIM identifier: SimNotInserted
Dec 12 21:52:24 dka ModemManager[911]: <warn>  Error checking if SIM was swapped: 'SimNotInserted'
Dec 12 21:52:25 dka ModemManager[911]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (unknown -> idle)
Dec 12 21:52:25 dka ModemManager[911]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (enabling -> enabled)
```

I have tried to `sudo service ModemManager restart`  but that does not help :

```
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-12 21:55:07 CET; 39s ago
 Main PID: 9905 (ModemManager)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 4.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
           ├─9905 /usr/sbin/ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
           └─9922 /usr/lib/libmbim/mbim-proxy

Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: opening device...
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Read max control message size from descriptors file: 512
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] MBIM device open
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Checking version info (15 retries)...
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] sending message as MBIM...
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: <info>  [cdc-wdm0] MBIM device is not QMI capable
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] MBIM device wasn't explicitly closed
Dec 12 21:55:10 dka ModemManager[9905]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] channel destroyed
Dec 12 21:55:22 dka ModemManager[9905]: <warn>  Modem couldn't be initialized: Couldn't check unlock status: Couldn't get SIM lock status after 6 retries
Dec 12 21:55:22 dka ModemManager[9905]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> failed)
```

How can I change the SIM card within the WWAN adapter without restarting linux ?

Comment: You probably can't.

Comment: At the software level, any/every mounted filesystem on the SIM card has be unmounted.  At the hardware level, the SIM card has to be hot-pluggable.  If you cannot confirm all of these requirements, then you cannot hotswap the SIM card.

Comment: Gabriela Garcia: why? @sawdust I didn't know a filesystem was mounted on the SIM. The hardware is USB plug-n-play but it's inside the laptop so I can't unplug it manually.